# RESTful provider Pipeline Batch error: "One or more errors occurred"

Tags: data-exchange-framework

Iam using sitecore 9 and installed the DEF, and have been trying to make it work. I followed the steps given here http://dataexchange.loveyourdemo.com/use-restful-provider/news/create-connector/add-pipeline-batch.html and created my pipeline batch.

When I run the pipeline batch though, it keeps running for a while and stops at an error. On checking the Pipeline.Batch.20180702.144518.txt that is created, I find the following:

---

ManagedPoolThread #10 16:45:18 INFO  [Data Exchange] Starting pipeline batch processing. (pipeline batch: Pipeline Batch)

ManagedPoolThread #10 16:45:18 INFO  [Data Exchange] Pipeline step reading data. (pipeline step: Read Resource Data Pipeline Step, plugin: Sitecore.DataExchange.Plugins.EndpointSettings)

8300 16:45:18 WARN  [Data Exchange] No access token is specified on the endpoint (pipeline step: Read Resource Data Pipeline Step, endpoint: RESTful Endpoint)

ManagedPoolThread #10 16:45:20 ERROR [Data Exchange] One or more errors occurred. (pipeline batch: Pipeline Batch, completed pipelines: 0)

### ManagedPoolThread #10 16:45:20 DEBUG [Data Exchange] Pipeline batch processor finished processing pipelines. (pipeline batch: Pipeline Batch, completed pipelines: 0)

I have no idea where to look to know exactly what the error is in "one or more errors occurred",  I need to know where the errors are logged in detail, if any.

Comment: In my experience, the default converters and processors often suppress full log information. My recommendation would be to decompile the default ones and add more logging where needed. After resolving the issue, it's probably best to switch back to the default ones to reduce solution complexity.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to set the log level of your pipeline batch.

[image]

After you select the level of logs you can view the logs in Sitecore on log field (see the picture) or  you can verify on disk at 
**Your Website location\App_Data\logs\DataExchange** folder

The code for RestfulProdider module can be found here: https://github.com/waughn/data-exchange-restful-provider/tree/master/2.0/src .

The error you get is related to RestFul provider,not Data Exchange Framework so I suggest you to bring it locally and debug it if you want to look deeper where is crashing.

Comment: Vlad Lobagiu has a point here. How much you can see in the logs depends only in the solution you are using. As I see the RESTful provider does not display inner exceptions.